# Editing a post that already has a pending edit gives weird error site

Tags: bug

I've just been trying to edit a question because it needed some code formatting. When I clicked on `edit`, it took me to this website:

[image]

I just asked myself: Shouldn't this be a error dialog on the main page instead of an unstyled HTML without title or anything that opens up?

This probably happens because the `edit` is a real link to the /edit page and when you go on that page, it tells you that there is already a pending edit. In my opinion, it would be more user-friendly if you check if there is a pending edit before directing the user to the /edit page.